# C# - Why is Enumerable<T> serializable for T that are not serializable?

Tags: c#, serialization

So far I've been considering `typeof(T).IsSerializable` to be true if `T` has attribute `[Serializable]`. (And unrelated to the confusingly named `ISerializable`). 
That first assumption is wrong; `IsSerializable` seems to be more complicated and I don't understand what it's meant be to be used for.

Examples where `IsSerializable` is true but the type isn't serializable:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
internal class Tests {

    private class MyClass {}

    [Test]
    public void TestIsNotSerialisable()
    {
        // Passes
        Assert.That(typeof(MyClass).IsSerializable, Is.False);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestIsNotSerialisableArray()
    {
        // Fails (is Serializable)
        Assert.That(typeof(MyClass[]).IsSerializable, Is.False);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestIsNotSerialisableList()
    {
        // Fails (is Serializable)
        Assert.That(typeof(List<MyClass>).IsSerializable, Is.False);
    }
}
```

[MSDN for IsSerializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isserializable(v=vs.110).aspx).

So why is `T[]` serializable even if `T` isn't?

Comment: Would `List<T>` be considered serializable if `T` is serializable, but one of `T`'s property's types isn't? What are you going to do with answers to this question? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN link you shared explains this in the **Remarks** section:

> If the current Type represents a constructed generic type, this property applies to the generic type definition from which the type was constructed. For example, if the current Type represents MyGenericType (MyGenericType(Of Integer) in Visual Basic), the value of this property is determined by MyGenericType.

So `List<T>` is considered serializable even though you can construct generic types from it that are not serializable, and the `IsSerializable` property does not reflect that.

Comment: Good point :) I bet the answer to that question is similar - even though arrays are not generic types, they do kind of behave like a generic type, and the "base implementation" of an array is serializable. I can't find any documentation on those, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between IsSerializable being true and actually being able to serialize an object without runtime issues.  Since List is serializable, the IsSerializable flag is always set.  However, if you looked into the UnderlyingSystemType, you'll see that MyClass is not serializable.

```
public void TestIsNotSerialisableList()
{
    Assert.That(typeof(List<MyClass>).UnderlyingSystemType.IsSerializable, Is.False);
}
```